# "In den Abend" or "im Abend" - the case of Abend followed by "in"

Tags: preposition

I wanted to say:

In the evening I go home.

I originally thought "in" would be followed by the accusative, which I found on the internet was correct:

> In den Abend gehe ich nach Hause.

But when I was looking at the following [article](https://www.germanveryeasy.com/in):

> as a temporal preposition, “in” can be translated as “in,” where a period of time is implicit. Take note that, as a temporal preposition, “in” is dative:

I then realised it must be:

> Im abend gehe ich nach Hause.

However, I found on some pages that "In den Abend" is correct and on others "im Abend" is correct instead.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preposition **in** is used with seconds, minutes, hours, weeks, months, and years.

> … in der ersten Minute …
>
> … in der zweiten Stunde …
>
> … in der dritten Februarwoche …
>
> … im dritten Monat schwanger …
>
> … im Jahr 1989 …

With other spots in time, you have to use the preposition **an**:

> … am Abend …
>
> … am 14. Februar …
>
> … an Werktagen …
>
> … an den Wochenenden …

Unfortunately, there's an exception. Some directions need **in**, too:

> … bis in den Morgen …

---

But your question was about dative vs. accusative case. That depends on whether you talk about a place or direction in time:

> Ihr Termin liegt in **der** dritt**en** Februarwoche.

The verb *liegen* requires a place.

> Wir verschieben Ihren Termin in **die** dritt**e** Februarwoche.

In contrary, the verb *verschieben* requires a direction.

You example is a bit tricky because the verb *gehen* can take both a place or a direction. An example with real places:

> Am Abend gehe ich am Strand.
>
> Am Abend gehe ich an den Strand.

In time, prefixed verbs as *losgehen* and *weitergehen* are preferred:

> Die Feier geht am Abend los.
>
> Die Feier geht bis in den Morgen weiter.

Comment: what about "In einer Stunde bin ich wieder da"

Comment: or "in den Abend hinein"?

Comment: The verb *sein* as a full verb/copula requires a place.

Comment: I finally understood your remark. You are right, end points and directions for the *an* places use *in*, too.

Answer (score 3):

None of those are correct. Here are two possibilities

> Am Abend gehe ich nach Hause
>   Abends gehe ich nach Hause

You could use "in den Abend" in a a context like this

> Ich habe bis in den Abend hinein gearbeitet (I worked **into** the evening)

Comment: Understood now! (an not in) What I wanted to say "In the evening, I went home" would it be then "In den Abend, ging ich nach Hause"?

Comment: No. "am Abend.." or "abends..."